# Cypress: Click a checkbox in a TD next to a td with specific text

Tags: checkbox, html-table, cypress

Is this possible?

My table is like this:

```
[ ]           Address string 1
[ ]           Address string 2
...
```

The markup:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <input class="hb-checkbox type="checkbox" id="byggSkjemaliste-element0-0-adresse-skjema-element-0">
    <div class="hb-label" data-e2e-selector="byggSkjemaliste-element0-0-adresse-skjema-element-0hb-checkbox-label">
      <label for="byggSkjemaliste-element0-0-adresse-skjema-element-0" id="byggSkjemaliste-element0-0-adresse-skjema-element-0-label"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  Address string"
</td>
```

A'd like to be able to find "Address string 1" in the table, then click the checkbox in the  to the left of that

Since I don't have control over the complex dynamic selectors created, it's very complex to try and use those when the table gets bigger, and when there are multiple tables on the page. Also, I'd like a more elegant way to select the checkbox in a specific row.

Comment: One problem here is that, although you've carefully established a label linked to the input, it _doesn't contain any useful text_. If that label was around "Address string 1" then https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro/ would let you do e.g. `findByRole("checkbox", { name: "Address string 1" })`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to follow the DOM layout, use navigation commands like `.prev()` of which the docs say

> Get the immediately preceding sibling of each element in a set of the elements.

```js
cy.contains('td', 'Address string 1')  // the cell containg the text you're looking for
  .prev('td')                          // previous sibling cell (td)
  .find('input')                       // pick the input within that cell
  .check();
```

---

The above is a first-stab based on the DOM structure, but I prefer the following Cypress commands (for simplicity, possibly more robust)

```js
cy.contains('tr', 'Address string 1')   // the row containing the address
                                        // looks in all children of tr,
                                        // so finds the label 4 levels down
  .find('input')                        // pick the input within that row
  .check();
```

Comment: Note the label doesn't actually contain that text.

Comment: Yes, I read your comment - am going to have to revise. It looks like the text is in the next cell.

Comment: Finally I think all is cosher